# DoModal crashed in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I am going throught  [Multiple Selection in a File Dialog](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3235/Multiple-Selection-in-a-File-Dialog?fid=13589&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&spc=Relaxed&fr=1#xx0xx) article of code project, 
this code works fine for visual studio 2005 but when i run it on visual studio 2010 it gives me an debug assertion as follow,

> Unhandled exception at 0x76f515de in MultiSelect.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x00000020.

At the following point,

```
 int ret = CFileDialog::DoModal();      //**Point where assersion occures**
```

Whole function is like follow(Note:-CFECFileDialog inherited from CFileDialog)

```
int CFECFileDialog::DoModal()
{
    if (Files)
    {
        delete[] Files;
        Files = NULL;
        delete[] Folder;
        Folder = NULL;
    }

    int ret = CFileDialog::DoModal();      //**Point where assersion occures**

    if (ret == IDCANCEL)
    {
        DWORD err = CommDlgExtendedError();
        if (err == FNERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL/*0x3003*/ && Files)
            ret = IDOK;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I also ask question for author of that article but he is not replying.

Comment: You'll need to learn how to debug exceptions like this.  Looking at the Call Stack to see the code that caused the crash is a necessary first step.

Comment: You sure your `CFECFileDialog` object is valid?

Comment: @HansPassant actual while debuging its throw me in assembly.so no chance of debuging step by step.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yes i am sure,my CFECFileDialog object is valid.

Comment: The Call Stack doesn't show assembly.  It shows a trace of the code that caused the problem.  If you don't know how to read it then of course you should put it in your question.

Comment: @HansPassant My apologies as I missed to indicate.But when i debug line by line continue and break popup apears with above mentioned message.

Comment: At the point you get the error, try to evaluate the `this` pointer. I bet it is `0x00000000`

Comment: @Marius thanks but pointer is like 

this = 0x001bf078 {CFECFileDialog hWnd=0x00000000}

Comment: Any specific changes with CFiledialog in vs2010??

Comment: Is `Folder` that you are deleting on the previous line, a valid pointer?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the project from CodeProject and got a crash at CFECFileDialog::OnFileNameChange. Using the VS2010 debugger and the "Go to disassembly" option, i saw that the crash was caused by GetParent returning NULL.

As I have no idea why the CommDlg_OpenSave_* macros were called with a "parent" handle, I just tried calling them with the "this" handle (m_hWnd). Works for me.

Try replacing each instance of "GetParent()->m_hWnd" by "m_hWnd" in CFECFileDialog::OnFileNameChange

EDIT: precision, I did not got the crash you had in DoModal

Comment: @Sankaganak Please let us know if the suggested fix in CFECFileDialog::OnFileNameChange made the crash go away